# Which Arquillian configuration should I use?

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss-arquillian

*I Am very new with Arquillian* and I have a simple question:

I am attemting to test a JAX-RS/Jersey Webservice deployed on tomcat 8, to do so I am using Jersey Client API to create requests to the endpoints. What I want to know is basically what container should I use with tomcat 8.. Should I use a remote one? Or a Embedded one?

I tried to use this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-weld-ee-embedded-1.1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.CR3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

But looks like the tests run before the tomcat is up..

Answer (score 0):

Running an embedded container will avoid you to install a tomcat on the test environment.

if you want a tomcat 8  container you should use :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
  <artifactId>arquillian-tomcat-embedded-8</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0.CR7</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

The container you set up is a weld (jboss CDI implementation) one.

The simplest way is then to [include arquillian API to your maven dependencies](http://arquillian.org/guides/getting_started/#add_the_arquillian_apis)  and use related annotation on your test classes

Run then the test as Junit one